# Fetch ProC SQL results as -nan instead of 0 when they are null

Tags: sql, c, oracle, null, proc

Using a struct defined as:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
typedef struct U_DataInfo{
    char    Cfg_Name[51];
    int     ID;
    // Others elements
    double  X;
    double  Y;
} U_DataInfo;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
```

Used Query is simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CFG_NAME, ID, /* some columns */, X, Y
          FROM table vi
          LEFT JOIN other_table ON other_table.other_id = vi.id
          LEFT JOIN /* other joins */
          /* where conditions */
```

In results, X and Y can be NULL.

[image]

Then using a cursor as:

```
U_DataInfo VL_Elem;
// Declare a dynamic cursor
EXEC SQL DECLARE SQL_DataCursor STATEMENT;
EXEC SQL PREPARE SQL_DataCursor FROM :SelectQuery;
EXEC SQL DECLARE DataCursor  CURSOR FOR SQL_DataCursor;
// Open the cursor
EXEC SQL OPEN DataCursor;
// Some stuff and while...
EXEC SQL FETCH DataCursor
        INTO :VL_Elem.Cfg_Name,
        :VL_Elem.ID,
         // Some Stuff
        :VL_Elem.X,
        :VL_Elem.Y;
// Some stuff
EXEC SQL CLOSE DataCursor;
```

Whenever SQL query returns NULL values for X and Y, their variables in U_DataInfo take 0.000 as value.

Can we make them -nan to be able to check for this later in code ?

Comment: are you sure that you are using Oracle DB?

Comment: Associated database is Oracle 12c, yes

Comment: "And a simple SQL query similar as select concerned_columns from table to fetch results into some of those structures."  OK, but you need to SHOW the "simple SQL query".  Please update your opening post.  I strongly suspect you need to use the NVL function in your "simple SQL query".

Comment: @EdStevens Updated with some "simple SQL query" as the full one is using lot of conditions, joins, cases, and should not be necessary. As I told, I DON'T want to use NVL, why should I, X and Y values CAN take null values in database. (see query results, it's intended) I'm only asking why fetching it from C code, then become "0.000" instead of -nan. Of course I could make use if NVL to transform NULL to "null" string or -999 for ex, then detect it from C code, but that's not really practical.